MVC-Template-Project-Runs-Screen-shrink-visual-studio-2022

When I create a new project from Visual Studio, the window shrinks and does not adjust to full screen, causing inconvenience and disrupting my workflow. I have to repeatedly create the ASP.NET MVC template to make it work correctly, which is time-consuming and frustrating. Is there a way to ensure that Visual Studio automatically adjusts to full screen or at least opens the new project window properly the first time, without needing repeated attempts? Additionally, are there specific settings or steps I can follow to resolve this issue permanently and enhance my productivity?

I should get the project run with full screen like below
